# Xamarin Forms Frame in Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have four frames, I want to enter in that number. When running on Windows, the numbers are fully visible, but when I run on Android, numbers are not visible or half appear.
I do not want to change outlines so that they get out of shape
And change their appearance
I'm beginner in xamarin
Please advise me to display the numbers correctly while running on Android without changing the appearance of my frames.

XAML:

```
    <Style TargetType="Frame" >
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    </Style>

</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Vertical" >

    <Image Source="d.png"  WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>

    <BoxView WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Pink" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    <Label Text="کد ارسال شده را اینجا وارد کنید" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"
           VerticalOptions="Center"/>


    <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="10"  BackgroundColor="White">

        <Frame WidthRequest="80" x:Name="frame1"  >
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Black"  FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MaxLength="1"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Focused="Entry_Focused" Unfocused="Entry_unFocused" />

        </Frame>

        <Frame WidthRequest="80"  x:Name="frame2" >
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="1"  Focused="Entry_Focused1" Unfocused="Entry_unFocused1" />

        </Frame>

        <Frame WidthRequest="80" x:Name="frame3" >
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Focused="Entry_Focused2" Unfocused="Entry_unFocused2" MaxLength="1" />

        </Frame>

        <Frame WidthRequest="80" x:Name="frame4"
             >
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               MaxLength="1"    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Focused="Entry_Focused3" Unfocused="Entry_unFocused3" />

        </Frame>

    </StackLayout>

    <Button   x:Name="Button"    Text="تایید"  TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="End" WidthRequest="340" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the specific heightrequest for android in the Frame

Here is running screenshot in android.

[image]

Here is code.

```
 <Frame  x:Name="frame1" WidthRequest="80" >
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Black"  FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MaxLength="1"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Focused="Entry_Focused" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" >


            </Entry>
            <Frame.HeightRequest>
                <OnPlatform Android="50" ></OnPlatform>


            </Frame.HeightRequest>

        </Frame>
```

Comment: @shaghayegh mahmoudi if it is helpful, please mark it as answer(Please click ✔ on the top right corner of this answer, the ✔ means mark it answer), it will help others who have similar issue.